# Add #ajax to an existing form

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to add the `#ajax` property to the add form of a simple existing content type.  I thought `hook_form_alter` would be the way to go, but the code below doesn't get me the updated results I'm looking for.  I've essentially repurposed this code from a `hook_menu` function that creates the fields manually, attaching the `#ajax` at creation, so I think the code itself is okay.  I'm just not sure if I'm using the incorrect hook, or if I'm missing something, or what the problem is.

```
function ajax_test_form_example_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {       
    $form['field_username']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'ajax_test_example_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'ajax-test-example-wrapper'
    );

    $form['text']['#prefix'] = '<div id="ajax-test-example-wrapper">';
    $form['text']['#suffix'] = '</div>';        
}

function ajax_test_example_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    if(isset($form_state['values']['username'])) {
        $form['field_number']['#description'] = 'Hi <strong> ' . $form_state['values']['username'] . '!';
    }
    return $form['field_number'];
}
```

Comment: what is your module name? did your code getting run?

Comment: My module is called ajax_test, and the Content Type is Example, thus ajax_test form example_node_form alter. I also have this alter function dpm the form variable, so I know it is being triggered.

Comment: I believe that you need to have your ajax callback attached to the submit button not to the textfield, I suggest that you also check examples module (check ajax example module on how to do that drupal.org/project/examples). In your question you pointed to having this ajax attached to a content type, why do you need that? is on a field of this content type or is the whole content type submit should be submitted using ajax call?

Comment: The ajax I'm looking to trigger is not things that would happen on the form's submission, but rather on, for example, the changing of a textfield's value.  And, as I said, this code works when I am creating a new form via the menu hook, so I know it doesn't have to hang on the form's submission.

Comment: As to why, I'd like to be able to hack into the content type's add form to, for example, preload the value of one field based on the input of another.  And I would like this to happen dynamically as the form is filled out, hence the #ajax property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that in order to add to an existing field you have to drill down into the array.  The correct place to add the property is

```
$form['field_username']['und'][0]['value']['#ajax']
```

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 8 use:

```
$form['field_username']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax']
```

Comment: Hi Mostfa, Good to see you here. I hope that you can learn here with us. Have a good day ;-)